# Как запустить flash() на странице и только потом вызвать переход на другую страницу

Tags: python, html, flask

У меня есть форма:

```
@air.route('/add_plane/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  # Добавление самолета
def add_plane():
    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.user_nick == "admin":
        form = AddPlane()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            plane = Plane(
                plane=form.plane.data,
                plane_age=form.plane_age.data,
                plane_num=form.plane_num.data,
                plane_wiki=form.plane_wiki.data,
                plane_photo=form.plane_photo.data,
                plane_id=form.plane_id.data,
                av_p=form.av_p.data,
            )
            plane.save()  # Сохраняем
            flash('Сообщение отправлено', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('shop.add_item'))
        return render_template("add_plane.html", form=form)
    else:
        return redirect("/login")
```

Я хочу чтобы после выполнения 15 строчки проходило несколько секунд, все это время на экране не происходит ничего кроме собственно говоря показа flash(), а после этого переход в redirect.

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: Управление страницей производится не на сервере, а на клиенте, вам нужно писать javascript-код с желаемым поведением

Comment: Понял, не мог ли бы вы примерно отправить как это должно выглядеть,